# How can I create a partitioned table 'like' an unpartitioned table with Hive HQL?

Tags: hive

I've got a table with two weeks worth of entries, and I would like to copy those entries into a table partitioned by date (creating it if it does not exist).

I'm writing a luigi task to do this, and I would love for it to be independent of the table schema--i.e. I wouldn't have to specify column names and types, and it would CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS when necessary.

I was hoping I could use:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_part
COMMENT 'This is a test table to see if partitioning works in this case'
PARTITIONED BY (event_date string)
AS select *, '2014-12-15' from source_db.source_table 
where event_at <'2014-12-16' and event_at >='2014-12-15';
```

But this of course fails with: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10068]: CREATE-TABLE-AS-SELECT does not support partitioning in the target table

I tried again with "like" with basically the same results.  Is there a way to do this that I am missing?  It doesn't have to be atomic.  Multiple sequential commands are fine.

Answer (score 1):

You do not do a create table as.

You create a table first using describe source_table and then you make an insert into table partition (event_date string)

2 steps it works better.